# Commiting local older commits after revert on public repository

Tags: git, github

Recently someone has pushed some incorrect changes to a branch I am developing and when I tried to pull from the git repo, correct code was overwritten by incorrect code without generating a conflict. As a result, I would like to revert the repo back to a common ancestor with my own local branch and then push my local changes to the repo.

I moved my local changes to temp_branch and then checked out the incorrect branch and reverted each of the commits/merges back to the common ancestor with temp_branch. However, when I try to merge my local changes back into the workflow from temp_branch, I still get conflicts with the reverted commits/merges (I guess because some of my changes are older?). Note: I can do git reset --hard back to this common ancestor and merge temp_branch with no problems/conflicts.

I know that I can force push my local changes onto the repo, but I am looking for a safer option that will preserve history and not require others problems if they have already pulled the incorrect version. Can anyone help me?

---

EDIT:

I have also tried `git merge -X theirs temp_branch`. This almost gives me what I want, but it still generates some conflicts and there are differences with temp_branch when I do `git diff`.

Comment: So what you did is call `git revert` for every commit made wrongly on "common ancestor"? Are the files in the same state as they were in common ancestor, i.e. does `git diff common_ancestor head_after_reverts` show any differences?

Comment: Exactly. Nothing shows up when I do `git diff` with the common ancestor.

Comment: The safest way may be to rebase your branch on top of the reverted one, using `git rebase head_after_reverts` when having checked out your `temp_branch`. You will have to solve the same conflicts, but it will be easy to make sure your commits won't get messed up. Your history should then show the wrong commits and their revert commits followed by your legit commits.

Comment: I can see how this might work in theory, but like `git merge -X theirs temp_branch`, the `git checkout temp_branch` + `git rebase head_after_reverts` produces non-trivial differences to the final state I know it should look like (i.e. my local branch). Maybe I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Are you able to recreate a minimal working example of what happened on some new repository?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle issue that I learned about [here](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed_new_merge) that needs to be considered, particularly when one of the "bad" changes involves a merge from another branch (like mine does).

Even if I worked through the conflicts of a merge/rebase to effectively correct the state of my branch with a full history, I have already shot myself in the foot if my changes were based on reverts that include merges from other branches. Months later, when you try to remerge these branches again, git will look back and see that the branches have already been merged and will either refuse to merge the content again or, worse, revert the original changes on the branch that they were made.

The link offers two safe options in this case:

1. Perform this reverse merge immediately and then revert the revert so that it will not occur in the future.
2. Abandon the old branch, create a new one, and let everyone know that development should continue on the new branch.

Perhaps someone has a better way of dealing with this problem, but these are the best solutions that I have found. In the end, I chose to make a new branch because this required the least amount of work and was less likely for a newbie like me to mess things up.